# Replacing NSColor with another in NSAttributedString

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview, nscolor

I am trying to replace one color with another in `NSAttributedString` to enable a dark mode in a pre-Mojave-app. I have a long `NSTextView` which holds the string.

Is there any way to remap or mutate the color that is already set in the NSTextView, similar to what the Mojave dark mode does with `NSColor.textColor`? If there are multiple documents open, formatting the string by enumerating through ranges and attributes one by one is very slow.

Hints & tips using Swift or Objective-C are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Make your own "adaptable" colors.

**Long Answer**

- Make a subclass of `NSColor` which has two readonly (to keep with
  NSColor being immutable) instance `NSColor` properties for the
  standard and dark colors.
- Add a class property to get/set which color should be used.
- Define your own `init`/`new` methods which take the underlying standard and dark colors.
- Add all of `NSColor`'s creation methods to your colors `@interface`
  marking them all `NS_UNAVAILBLE` – this prevents accidental use of
  them.
- Override all the methods required – see `NSColor.h` (use "Jump to
  Definition" in Xcode to open it). Each override simply directs the
  method to the appropriate standard or dark color. This is just a
  bunch of boilerplate code.
- Now use your subclass to color your `NSAttributedString`. When you
  wish to switch mode use the class property to switch all the colors
  on-the-fly and redraw your string.

HTH

Comment: Thank you. Paulo Andrade has also made a DynamicColor class as a quick fix for dark/light mode problems. It's easy to adapt the code to support such modes on older macs too.
https://pfandrade.me/blog/adopting-dark-mode-and-older-macs/